# VBA create function within a function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm trying this in VBA. But it says: "compile error". What am I doing wrong?

```
Function My_Forecast(a As Double, x As range, y As range) As Double

My_Forecast = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(a, 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(x, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, x, 1)): Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(x, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, x, 1) + 1), Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(y, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, x, 1)): Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(y, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, x, 1) + 1))

End Function
```

The function `My_x1`, `My_x2`, `My_y1`, `My_y2` separately work resulting in a number, for example:

```
Function My_x1(a As Double, x As range, y As range) As Double
    My_x1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(x, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, x, 1))
End Function
```

Comment: What's that colon doing in that `My_Forecast = ` line? Also, it looks like it's spanning two lines in VBA. Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Statements in VBA are terminated by a NEWLINE token. If you want a long statement to span multiple _physical_ lines of code, it's still a single _logical_ line of code if you use _line continuation_ tokens. Those are defined as a whitespace followed by an underscore, followed by a NEWLINE. Note that there's a maximum of physical lines a logical line of code is allowed to span: beyond 20 or so, you'll get a "too many line continuations" compile error.

Comment: The colon character here is acting as a _statement separator_, which means both sides of it are expected to consist of a complete, legal instruction. I suspect you intend to pass a `Range` to the forecast function, built from the results of the INDEX/MATCH lookups. Declare a `Range` object and assign it in its own separate instruction. In general, avoid cramming as many statements as possible in a single instruction: VBA/code reads much better vertically - this isn't an Excel formula, there shouldn't be a need for so much horizontal scrolling!